# Как расположить div по средине? (bootstrap)

Tags: bootstrap

```css
.specails__img img {
 width: 150px;
 height: 150px;
}
.specailsText {
 background: #f8f8f8;
 text-align: center;
 width: 150px;
 height: 150px;
 padding: 35px 20px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
     <div class="specails__img">
      <img src="img/pictureOne.jpg">
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
     <div class="specailsText">
      <p>Grees fava</p>
      <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit Pellentesque velenim</span>
      <p>17 $</p>
     </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

На мобильной версии мне нужно что бы блок был расположен по средине экрана вот как показано на картинке, а пока он сбоку слева. Как исправить ситуацию?  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос вёрстку и стили.

Answer (score 0):

Решила вопрос используя `display: block;margin: 0 auto;` так и не найди ответа в bootstrap(